# Using SQL request to copy rows and edit a value, but need to improve it a bit

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have found a request to copy a player's inventory for a game's database (for moderation stuff), so I can enter my username instead of my characterId (name from characters table, and the inventory is from items and doesn't have the name column but characterId), I tried using a join to replace the characterId by the name, but it only work from the character I want to copy and not the character where it is pasted

```
DELETE i FROM items i
JOIN characters c ON c.characterId=i.characterId
WHERE c.name='Name1'

INSERT INTO items (characterId , itemId , amount , sort , equipSlot , maxUpgrade , currentUpgrade , statMod , isTradable , uniqueId , attached)
    SELECT 1 , itemId , amount , sort , equipSlot , maxUpgrade , currentUpgrade , statMod , isTradable , uniqueId , attached
    FROM items i 
    JOIN characters c ON i.characterId=c.characterId
WHERE c.name='Name2'
```

So the "Name1" (my character) has for accountId 1, and the character I want to copy his inventory "Name2", has for characterId 2, so for my request instead of having `SELECT 1 , itemId...`, I want to be able to use `SELECT "Name1" , itemId...`, so no need to use other request to find the characterId by searching the name, then getting characterId to implement in the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better solution. Check it.

```
INSERT INTO ITEMS (CHARACTERID,
                   ITEMID,
                   AMOUNT,
                   SORT,
                   EQUIPSLOT,
                   MAXUPGRADE,
                   CURRENTUPGRADE,
                   STATMOD,
                   ISTRADABLE,
                   UNIQUEID,
                   ATTACHED)
SELECT C2.CHARACTERID,
       I.ITEMID,
       I.AMOUNT,
       I.SORT,
       I.EQUIPSLOT,
       I.MAXUPGRADE,
       I.CURRENTUPGRADE,
       I.STATMOD,
       I.ISTRADABLE,
       I.UNIQUEID,
       I.ATTACHED
  FROM ITEMS I
       INNER JOIN CHARACTERS C
          ON I.CHARACTERID = C.CHARACTERID AND C.NAME = 'Name2'
       INNER JOIN CHARACTERS C2 ON C2.NAME = 'Name1'
```

Comment: @SamyPereger Came up with a better solution. Check it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted thanks, I tried by my side and done something else and was going to aply new things I learned to this case, and I think that would be close to what I would do, except I'd probably add a WHERE somehow